# What is a balancing movement for overhead press?

Tags: overheadpress

I have read about pull ups/chin up. Is there anything I can do with a barbell?

My workout regime now consists of squats, deadlift, lunges, bench press, rows and overhead press.

Comment: Depending on the type of bench you have, you could do reverse press (Pull yourself up to the bar, rather than pressing the bar away from you), but this would require a bench that you could remove the seat or other arrangement to where you could hang completely from the bar. (Think a pushup position, but underneath the bar so you can pull yourself up).

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing barbell rows and deadlifts I think you're okay. The [barbell row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html) will work the upper back and posterior deltoid, and the [deadlift](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/BBDeadlift.html) will do your traps (upper/mid/lowers).

The only other I can think of is [the clean](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/Clean.html), since the bar is very close to your body and your pulling up with a similar grip. In fact, [here's an existing Q&A that gets into it a bit](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/improve-overhead-press-by-cleaning?rq=1).

Comment: I was thinking upright row, simply because it is the most opposite in terms of the movement being performed. But, admittedly, that doesn't always mean it works the opposing muscles well. What do you think about the upright row?

Comment: @Tyler the upright row is one of those things I avoid. The one time I did it my wrists felt horrible and I've seen (and read) of a decent amount of shoulder injuries coming from them. The risk is to high for me on that one, and I can get the benefits from other safer movements.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically. A wide grip pull up would be the 'balancing movement' of an overhead press. If you want to take care of your shoulders, I would look into doing some band pull aparts and some face pulls with a rope at the beginning of your workout. Especially if you are planning on doing some heavy pressing movements (bench, overhead, dips, etc)

Hope that helps,

Mike